# Getting "Unterminated [] set." Error in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am working with following regex in C#

```
Regex find = new Regex("[,\"]url(?<Url>[^\\]+)\\u0026");
```

and getting this error:

```
"System.ArgumentException: parsing "[,"]url([^\]+)\u0026" - Unterminated [] set.
```

I'm kind of new to regular expressions so correct me if I'm wrong. The regular expression is supposed to extract urls from text matching like:

,url=http://domain.com\u0026

"url=http://hello.com\u0026

Comment: \u0026 is NOT a unicode identifier, but a string literal i.e. how the text is in the memory - a six digit string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a verbatim string:

```
Regex find = new Regex(@"[,""]url(?<Url>[^\\]+)\\u0026");
```

Edit: However, I'd change the regex to

```
Regex find = new Regex(@"(?<=[,""]url=)[^\\]+(?=\\u0026)");
```

Then the entire match is the URL itself. No need for a capturing sub-group.

Comment: I tried verbatim/literal string myself and your version as well...but that wouldn't even compile in VS2008 Pro? It's giving syntax error.

Comment: Just escape the quote with ""

Comment: just tried:

'string reg = @"(?<=[,""])url=([^\]+?)(?=\u0026)";
Regex find = new Regex(reg);'

still getting the same "Unterminated Set" error?

Comment: Use this: new Regex(@"(?<=[,""])url=(?<Url>[^\\\]+)(?=\\u0026)"); *edit* gar, swallowing my \\!

Comment: The code is working now, but its not working correctly i.e. Not finding any matches because .Net regex engine is treating \u0026 as a unicode symbol...but actually "\u0026" appears in the text AS-IS...so we need to do a literal comparison. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Can you update your answer with the regex that you are currently using? As long as you're escaping the \ properly it should be matching the string literal.

Comment: Regex find = new Regex(@"[,""]url=(?<Url>[^\\]+)(\\u00)");

Programs runs but its not finding any matches.

Comment: I ran it through http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx with the source string you posted and both URLs get matched and extracted fine.

Comment: Thanks, its working now! Final Regex: = 'new Regex(@"(?<First>[,""]url=)(?<Url>[^\\]+)(?<Last>\\u00)");' I'm ignoring First and Last groups.

Answer (score 8):

You're escaping one of the brackets with \] which means you have an unterminated [.

This [cheat sheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) is great for .NET regexs, I have it printed out on my desk. Totally recommend it! To match \ you want \\.

Oh yeah, missed the lack of verbatim without the first edit. Go for Tim's suggestion I'd say.

One other online tool which is really handy for quick testing is [Derek Slager's online tool](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx).