# Extracting Groups and Sub-groups in RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

This question is, in a way, continuation of my previously answered question: [Getting "Unterminated [] set." Error in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344450/getting-unterminated-set-error-in-c)

I'm using regular expression in C# to extract URLs:

```
Regex find = new Regex(@"(?<First>[,""]url=)(?<Url>[^\\]+)(?<Last>\\u00)");
```

Where the text contains URLs in the format:

*,url=http://domain.com?itag=25\u0026,url=http://hello.com?itag=11\u0026*

I'm getting the entire URL in 'Url' group, but I'd also like to have the itag value in a separate "iTag" group. I know this can be done using sub-groups and I've been trying but can't figure out exactly how to do this.

Comment: check this site out: http://txt2re.com/index.php3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already have named groups defined in the Regex. The syntax `?<First>` is naming everything within those parenthesis `First`.

When you match using `Regex`, using the `Groups` property to access the `GroupCollection` and extract a group value by name.

```
var first = regex.Match(line).Groups["First"].Value;
```

This will add an additional group for iTag, but retain the full Url. Move it outside the other parenthesis to change this.

```
(?<First>[,""]url=)(?<Url>[^\?]+?itag=(?<iTag>[0-9]*))(?<Last>\\u0026)
```

Here's the code.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<First>[,\"]url=)(?<Url>[^\\?]*\\?itag=(?<iTag>[0-9]*))(?<Last>\\u0026)");
string input = ",url=http://domain.com?itag=25\u0026,url=http://hello.com?itag=11\u0026";

foreach(Match match in regex.Matches(input))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("1. "+match);
    System.Console.WriteLine("  1. "+match.Groups["First"]);
    System.Console.WriteLine("  2. "+match.Groups["Url"]);
    System.Console.WriteLine("  3. "+match.Groups["iTag"]);
    System.Console.WriteLine("  4. "+match.Groups["Last"]);
}
```

Results:

```
1. ,url=http://domain.com?itag=25&
  1. ,url=
  2. http://domain.com?itag=25
  3. 25
  4. &
1. ,url=http://hello.com?itag=11&
  1. ,url=
  2. http://hello.com?itag=11
  3. 11
  4. &
```

Comment: It's not capturing anything, probably because of [^\\] which goes over entire url before itag part is processed. I changed it to `(?<First>[,""]url=)(?<Url>[^&]+itag=(?<iTag>[0-9]*)[^\\]+)(?<Last>\\u0026)` but that capturing all links in the text as one url?

Comment: You're right, it was working [here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) for some reason but not in code. Amended answer.